# why i get 502 Bad Gataway error with nginx 1.18.0

Tags: nginx, flask

I'm trying to deploy my flask app on a local server (my university server) through remote desktop.

my application is build using flask and as for the current i'm just trying to deploy it on the development server, just to know that there is a hope for it to be running.

my project is inside venv and when i tried to deploy it i get this error:

"10.0.0.1 - - [18/May/2021 09:50:45] code 400, message Bad request syntax ("\x16\x03\x01\x00½\x01\x00\x00¹\x03\x03,\x05ù\x96ï;Ì\x02E\x8a\xadJüÃÅG\x8a¡\x8b<Ô\x0e\x8e\xad\x97ÔÝ\x82Yx\x048\x0"

and on the web side i get 502 bad getaway.

this is how i run my app:

```
def flask_main_run():
    app = get_app()
    app = manage_app(app)
    db = get_db()
    db.create_all()
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=443)
```

how can i overcome this error and deploy my app on a local server?

Comment: What is your nginx configuration? It seems like you're getting SSL requests undecoded into your flask app.

Comment: I'm sorry for my ignorance, but this is the first time that i'm trying to deploy web app. i'm working with windows 10 and i can't locate my nginx.conf file. do i need to write it from scratch or it should be created automatically when i run my app through the flask-run?

Comment: No, nginx is not invoked when you run your app through flask run. nginx would be the server handling the request; if you're just developing your app locally, run it on a custom port (like 5000), and access your app through that port. Since you mention in your title that nginx, I'm guessing it's somewhere in the chain and something you have installed yourself (flask does not install or start nginx, that's done as a separate task. nginx is then configured as shown in the answer below to route requests to your flask app when they arrive to nginx).

Comment: Thank for your answers. apperantley the problem was with some restriction that my university server had and the IT guys fixed it so i cant tell what was their solution. the nginx conf file has configured in their main servers and iv'e been orders not to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Hope Nginx will be also running on port 80 & 443, and you are trying to bind the same port in flask, so your flask app is not running at all.

Change the flask app port to something else like 9000, and put proxy_pass in nginx listen server as:

```
proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:9000
```